# mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, fastapi, authlib

I am trying to integrate gitlab in my fastapi project however, this problem is killing me. I am using authlib for it. The process of gitlab integration is when a user hits a connect button then gitlab authorization window pops up where when authorize button is clicked it runs redirect_url which is my api url(`http://localhost:8888/auth/gitlab?code=asdkjfasdjfkasdjkfasjdkjlsadajk&state=_gitlab`). This is the code

```
if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=settings.SECRET_KEY)
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

config = Config(".env")
oauth = OAuth(config)
oauth.register(
    name="gitlab",
    client_id=settings.GITLAB_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=settings.GITLAB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorize_url="https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize",
    client_kwargs={"scope": "read_user+profile"},
)

@app.get("/auth/gitlab")
async def auth_gitlab(request: Request):
    print("###################")
    print("request", request, request.session)
    # {'_gitlab_authlib_redirect_uri_': 'http://localhost:8888/auth/gitlab'}
    gitlab = oauth.create_client("gitlab")
    try:
        token = await gitlab.authorize_access_token(request)
        print("token", token)
        user = await gitlab.parse_id_token(request, token)
        print("user", dict(user))
        return {"token": token}
    except OAuthError as error:
        print("oauth error", error, error.error)
```

my oauth url for the popup is

```
const oauthUrl = `${GITLAB_URL}/oauth/authorize?client_id=${client_id}&response_type=code&scope=${scope}&state=${
          state + '_gitlab'
        }&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&allow_signup=${allow_signup}`
```

I used both 0.15.4 and 1.0.0a2 version of Authlib and still getting same issue.

UPDATE:
my request.session from /auth/gitlab looks like

```
{'_state_gitlab_WiBjFgSNd5BV1A7hlDHX0': {'data': {'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8888/auth/gitlab', 'url': 'https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=e2dc9edc72dbcf5524910eca1d0577473b6005a833c97&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fauth%2Fgitlab&scope=read_user%2Bprofile&state=WiBjFgSNd5BV1A7hlDHX0'}, 'exp': 1632275167.3455658}, '_state_gitlab_3YUfQJ4ubbNjErkqY4dJ7ZQMzzmCqt': {'data': {'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8888/auth/gitlab', 'url': 'https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=e2dc9edc72dbcf5524910eca1d0577473b6005a833c97&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fauth%2Fgitlab&scope=read_user%2Bprofile&state=3YUfQJ4ubbNjErkqY4dJ7ZQMzzmCqt'}, 'exp': 1632275280.9188702}, '_state_gitlab_S3OQ93EDvralFGYiu5HxRWxUMWZFQh': {'data': {'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8888/auth/gitlab', 'url': 'https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=e2dc9edc72dbcf5524910eca1d0577473b6005a833c97&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fauth%2Fgitlab&scope=read_user%2Bprofile&state=S3OQ93EDvralFGYiu5HxRWxUMWZFQh'}, 'exp': 1632275404.760191}, '_state_gitlab_vImiUiWK4VIUL82PywWlIZ1K9yA5Ss': {'data': {'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8888/auth/gitlab', 'url': 'https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=e2dc9edc72dbcf5524910eca1d0577473b6005a833c97&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fauth%2Fgitlab&scope=read_user%2Bprofile&state=vImiUiWK4VIUL82PywWlIZ1K9yA5Ss'}, 'exp': 1632275509.933466}}
```

When I changed oauth_url for pop up to

```
const oauthUrl = `${GITLAB_URL}/oauth/authorize?client_id=${client_id}&response_type=code&scope=${scope}&state=${
          state + 'WiBjFgSNd5BV1A7hlDHX0'
        }&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&allow_signup=${allow_signup}`
```

I get python `TypeError: Invalid type for url. Expected str or httpx.URL, got <class 'NoneType'>: None`

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the `https_only` argument on the SessionMiddleware options.
It worked only if i set it to True.